# IBDesignable View with Dynamic Constraints: Misplaced Children when Rendering

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode-storyboard, ibdesignable

I am trying to build (programmatically) a new view and use `IBDesignable` attribute to simplify this process and to show views in storyboard instead of white rectangles.

Here is a class with two subviews: `UILabel` and `UIImageView`. I am adding them dynamically to the parent view and set a couple of constraints for them:

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable
class ChoiceView: UIView {

    enum ChoiceState {
        case empty, chosen
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setupViewForState(.empty)
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupViewForState(.empty)
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
    }

    private func setupViewForState(_ state: ChoiceState) {
        guard case .empty = state else { return } // single case for now

        let placeholder = UILabel()
        let choiceImage = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "plus_small"))
        placeholder.text = "None"
        placeholder.textAlignment = .right
        choiceImage.contentMode = .center

        let constraintFormats = [
            "H:|-0-[placeholder]-10-[choice(50)]-0-|",
            "V:|-0-[placeholder]-0-|",
            "V:|-0-[choice]-0-|"
        ]

        let views = ["placeholder": placeholder, "choice": choiceImage]

        translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        placeholder.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        choiceImage.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        addSubview(placeholder)
        addSubview(choiceImage)

        let constraints = constraintFormats.flatMap {
            NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(
                withVisualFormat: $0,
                options: .directionLeadingToTrailing,
                metrics: nil,
                views: views)
        }        

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(constraints)
    }

}
```

These are not perfect yet, but at least - shown in simulator:
[image: cell in simulator]

But when I reload views in storyboard builder, I see this:
[image: cell in storyboard]

As you can see, the constraints are not enforced in storyboard and the image is not shown. Do you know how to fix that? Or, is it even possible to get the same picture in both storyboard and simulator?

---

> **Solution**: Please look at @DonMag answer. It allows to see result I was expecting (see picture attached).

[image]

Comment: Since IB is a *design-time* tool, you cannot expect *code* to be processed in it. So, no, it is not possible.

Comment: I understand it, but you see, the label is shown correctly, with title set in code. Therefore, I though it is possible to do the same for `UIImage`.

Comment: @devforfu did you check my answer?

Comment: That's not what I see. Your first screenshot - done in the simulator, which is processing your coded constraints - looks good. But that second screenshot - the one that isn't processing code? The label with "None" is top left, not left of the image. And the image isn't visible *because* the code to set it isn't being executed. (I'll guess that if you set the image in IB you'll see it in the same spot as the label. But that depends on what else you did in IB.)

Comment: @dfd But the label text is not set inside of IB :) Ok, I see what you mean, constraints are not enforced before actual code execution.

Comment: @dfd FYI, please check the solution provided below. That is the result  I was looking for.

Comment: Glad you found your solution! Saving this for future reference. (I'm basically a code-only guy. For now.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do not set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false` for your Designable view ***itself***.

```
    let views = ["placeholder": placeholder, "choice": choiceImage]

    // don't do this one
    //translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    placeholder.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    choiceImage.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    addSubview(placeholder)
    addSubview(choiceImage)
```

Also, to see your "choice" image in IB:

```
    let theBundle = Bundle(for: type(of: self))
    let choiceImage = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "plus_small", in: theBundle, compatibleWith: self.traitCollection))
    //
    //let choiceImage = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "plus_small"))
    ...
```

Comment: Completely valid solution. Both image and label are displayed and aligned correctly.

Comment: Why does this cause issues?, solved it for me, thanks!